# mentioning time span in a thesis (from 2019 to 2020)

Tags: academic-writing, structure, word-choice, sentence-structure

I would like to know if there is a need for the word "year" in this part of the sentence:

> "..., that took place from the 2019 to 2020,...".

Should it be:

> "..., that took place from the year 2019 to the year 2020,..."

or

> "..., that took place from 2019 to 2020,..."

I have searched for an answer, but I only found articles about dates. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to phrase this is either: that took place in 2019 and 2020, of: that took place from 2019 to 2020.